# same row and column names R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, pivot

I am doing a change matrix of two periods of Land Cover in R that I usually/easily do in Excel using pivot table.

I got how to do the pivot table way in R but I'm having a bit trouble in manipulating the data frame further.

I NEED TO HAVE THE EXACT ROWS AND COLUMNS from data frames with unequal rows and columns and just put 0 to the missing rows/columns.

Sample:

```
df <- matrix(1:20, 4)
colnames(df) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
rownames(df) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df1 <- df[-3,]

df1
```

In 'df1', rows 'c' and 'e' is missing. I started making a for loop that goes into rows and look for what's missing:

```
FinalTable <- function (df){
  for (i in rownames(df)){
    if (i != colnames(df)){
      print ('not equal')
    }
  }
}
```

After this, I need to do rbind to add the column that is missing in the row.

I appreciate your help.

I can send the raw and desired table for your reference.

Thanks!

Nando

Comment: Thanks! I checked on it. It's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a `matrix` with full names, then use `match` to get the rows and column index based on the matching row names and column names in the original and new matrix, and then assign it to the new dataset

```
un1 <- sort(union(rownames(df1), colnames(df1)))
m1 <- matrix(0, dimnames = list(un1, un1), ncol=length(un1), nrow=length(un1))
i1 <- match(rownames(m1), rownames(df1), nomatch = 0)
j1 <- match(colnames(m1), colnames(df1), nomatch = 0)
i2 <- match(rownames(df1), rownames(m1))
j2 <- match(colnames(df1), colnames(m1))
m1[i2,j2] <- df1[i1,j1]
m1   
#  a b  c  d  e
#a 1 5  9 13 17
#b 2 6 10 14 18
#c 0 0  0  0  0
#d 4 8 12 16 20
#e 0 0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I just put 'as.matrix' to df1[i1,j1] on my data frame. Thank you very much!